# How to handle cookies like a web browser using App Engine url fetch service?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cookies

I have seen many questions about using cookies with url fetch on App Engine, but many people doing it incorrectly, and no confirmed-as-working solutions on Java App Engine.

All I want to do is:

1. Make one request
2. Get the cookies from that request.
3. Make a second request, with those cookies.

How hard can it be??

This is easy to do on the dev server, because the dev server copies cookies across requests automatically - and indeed it's impossible to stop it doing this. But the real App Engine urlfetch service does *not* do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, fetchOptions.doNotFollowRedirects())
```

to create the request object.

The `doNotFollowRedirects()` is **essential** for some reason. I don't understand why.

Then get the set-cookie headers from the response (ones whose names `equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")`) and create a corresponding `Cookie` header - trimming off everything after the semicolon in each Set-Cookie header, if there is one, and then concatenating all the cookies together with `;` as a separator.

This doesn't correctly deal with expiration etc., but this should be enough for most purposes.