# URLFetchService using GAE returns null when trying to fetch New York Times page

Tags: java, google-app-engine, httprequest, urlfetch

I'm using the following code to fetch the html of a New York Times page and unfortunately, this is returning null. I have tried with other websites (CNN, The Guardian, etc) and they work fine. I'm using the URLFetchService from Google App Engine.

Here's the code snippet. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
//url = https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/02/us/politics/health-care-paul-ryan-fred-upton-congress.html

private String extractFromUrl(String url, boolean forced) throws java.io.IOException, org.xml.sax.SAXException,
                      de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException  {

    Future<HTTPResponse> urlFuture = getMultiResponse(url);

    HTTPResponse urlResponse = null;
    try {
        urlResponse = urlFuture.get(); // Returns null here
    } catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( ExecutionException ee ) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }

    String urlResponseString = new String(urlResponse.getContent());
    return urlResponseString;
}

public Future<HTTPResponse> getMultiResponse(String website) {
    URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(website);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.followRedirects();
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, fetchOptions);
    Future<HTTPResponse> futureResponse = fetcher.fetchAsync(request);
    return futureResponse;
}
```

The exception I'm getting is this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/02/us/politics/health-care-paul-ryan-fred-upton-congress.html, error: Received exception executing http method GET against URL https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/02/us/politics/health-care-paul-ryan-fred-upton-congress.html: null
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.setExceptionResult(FutureWrapper.java:66)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
[INFO]  at main.java.com.myapp.app.MyServlet.extractFromUrl(MyServlet.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the verbose output of curl, you can see that the website tries to set a cookie and redirects you in case the cookie is not accepted.

It appears that the times will redirect you 7 times before giving up -

```
$ curl --verbose -L "https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/02/us/politics/health-care-paul-ryan-fred-upton-congress.html" 2>&1 | grep 303 | wc -l
7
```

It appears that the maximum number of redirects for UrlFetch is 5 [0].

In order to successfully crawl www.nytimes.com, you will have to disable following redirects and handle the cookie logic yourself. Some inspiration here [1] and here [2]

[0] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/F2dX3LqOrhY

[1] https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-java/pE0xak7LRxg/M__U-SM3YMMJ

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588616/7947020

Comment: Thank you. I'll look up those suggestions.

Comment: Finally got to look up your suggestions and got my code working. After setting the cookie on first request, NYT redirects you to another page, where they set two more cookies. Then they redirect you back to the original page where all the three cookies (one from 1st request, two more from 2nd request from the redirect) are used.

Comment: @BlueChips23 Awesome! It's likely this behavior will change again, so make sure you have some good logging and error handling in place in case this is not just a one off.